# Questions about telecom networks

Tags: discussion

Perhaps this question is not supposed to be here, but I really need this answered! Is it the right place to ask questions about telecommunications networks? Like if I have some questions about telecom nodes (MSC servers, Media gateways, RNCs, BSCs, eNodeBs, etc) or cellular network design and working, can I ask them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - on topic!

**1)** If not here, where should users go? Which Stack Exchange site is it?

**2)** From POTS to ISDN to VoIP to IP telephony, all are part of a network.

**3)** Convergence. If you don't know what is replaced you gonna have a hard time getting user and technical requirements right.

**4)** Cellular networks are increasingly an alternative to cable links. Can't hurt to know how other services on the same node behave. For instance, comparison of voice and data services on the same node.

**5)** These questions touch service provider issues which may attract insiders to give some insight.